# How can I merge array's rows based on a specific item?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
$arr = [[1, "red"],
        [2, "blue"],
        [3, "yellow"],
        [1, "green"],
        [4, "green"],
        [3, "red"]];
```

And this is expected result:

```
$output = [[1, ["red", "green"]],
           [2, ["blue"]],
           [3, ["yellow","red"]],
           [4, ["green"]]];
```

Is doing that possible by PHP?

Comment: Yes it is possible in PHP. A simple foreach loop will do it.

Comment: `[3, ["yellow","red"]]` - there's no `yellow` withon your input. Update your expected output

Answer (score 0):

That structure is not really handy, taking in count that you could use the index number as array key, so if it was me I would stick with the structure that in my answer is created for array $temp. Anyway, for your desired result you can do:

```
  $arr = [[1, "red"],
          [2, "blue"],
          [3, "red"],
          [1, "green"],
          [4, "green"],
          [2, "red"]];
  $res = array();
  $temp = array();
  $keys = array();
  foreach ($arr as $v) {
      $temp[$v[0]][] = $v[1];
  }
  foreach (array_keys($temp) as $k) {
      $res[]=array($k,$temp[$k]);
  }
```

Also, your expected result because the index, looks more like:

```
$output = [[1, ["red", "green"]],
           [2, ["blue","red"]],
           [3, ["red"]],
           [4, ["green"]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via a reduction transformation and then truncate the keys after building up the desired output via the `array_values` statement.

```
//take only values (re-indexing 0..4)
$output = array_values(
  //build associative array with the value being a 'tuple'
  //containing the index and a list of values belonging to that index
  array_reduce($arr, function ($carry, $item) {

    //assign some names for clarity
    $index = $item[0];
    $color = $item[1];

    if (!isset($carry[$index])) {
      //build up empty tuple
      $carry[$index] = [$index, []];
    }

    //add the color
    $carry[$index][1][] = $color;

    return $carry;

  }, [])
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Short solution using `foreach` loop and `array_values` function:

```
$arr = [[1, "red"], [2, "blue"], [3, "red"], [1, "green"], [4, "green"], [2, "red"]];

$result = [];
foreach ($arr as $pair) {
    list($k, $v) = $pair;
    (isset($result[$k]))? $result[$k][1][] = $v : $result[$k] = [$k, [$v]];
}
$result = array_values($result);
```